# D3 JS Layout Tree connected to CrossFilter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

How would I connect a D3.JS [Tree Layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout) with [CrossFilter](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/)?

Suppose I have [this example tree](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html). I then extract a list of tree nodes, which serves as the input data set for CrossFilter.

```
// Compute the new tree layout.
var nodes = tree.nodes(root);
var data = crossfilter(nodes);
var bySize = data.dimension(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

I then want to filter based on size, and dynamically update the tree based on this filtering.  Any thoughts on how I should update the tree data source?

Would I need to write the function to get back to the original input tree data structure, such as:

`treeJson = graph2tree(filteredNodes, filteredEdges)`

or is there there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a tree, you could use the entire path to each element as your dimension key. Then any branch is a contiguous range of the dimension.

E.g. This sorts automatically into branches:
A.1
A.2
A.3
B.1

Then have another dimension keyed on size, and use treeDim.top(Infinity) or .group() to get your items. They aren't in tree structure but at least they're in order, and you could use d3.nest to make them into a tree.

... and if you also want to filter on branches, you're set up, just set the range e.g to [A,B)